# adjacency matrix/Floyd/Warshall in lisp

Tags: graph, matrix, lisp, clisp, floyd-warshall

Apparently my teacher believes that even if we don't have time to learn stuff (nor enough examples) we should move on, so I now need to know how to make Floyd-Warshall's and Warshall's algorithms in clisp.

As I did with prolog, my problem is to generate the adjacency matrix from the graph, in this case it would be a list of lists, e.g.:

```
((A B) (A C) (A D) (B C) (C D))
```

That should generate:

```
((0 1 1 1) (1 0 1 9) (1 1 0 1) (1 9 1 0))
```

I've got this:

```
(defun floyd(graph)
    (setf l (length graph)) 
    (setf mat (matrix l graph))
)

(defun matrix(l graph)
    (setf matrix (make-array (list l l)))
    (dotimes (i l)
        (dotimes (j l)
            (if (= i j)
                (setf (aref matrix i j) 0)
                (setf (aref matrix i j) ???)
            )
        )
    )
    matrix
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, and kind of off-topic: If I could solve my own question, should I reply myself for the sake of having an answered question?

Comment: There is a [Self Learner badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/14/self-learner) if you answer your own question with a score of 3 or more. I'd take that as a hint regarding whether it is acceptable to reply with a solution yourself.

Comment: As a start for more idiomatic code, use [`let`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm) instead of `setf` for `l`, `mat` and `matrix`.

Comment: CLISP is an implementation, the language is called Common Lisp or short CL. You also need to declare variables (for example using LET). Setting arbitrary undefined variables is not a good idea. Also don't format code with single parentheses on a line.

Comment: As a warm up exercise, consider writing a function that returns the nodes for the graph, e.g `(A B C D)`.

Comment: Your teacher will be much more impressed with your brilliance if you solve it with [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) rather than rely on side effects. See if you can eliminate the use of `SETF`.

Comment: @Terje thank you very much for all of your comments, I'll try the warm up exercise, and if I have time I'll try to understand pure functions xD problem is, I have like 36 hours now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the Wikipedia pseudo-code into Common Lisp with type declarations. 
The return type declaration is non-standard, I used SBCL.
I guess this won't run but it might give you an idea how Lisp code is supposed to look like.

```
(defparameter *n* 5)
(defparameter *path*
  (make-array (list *n* *n*)
          :element-type '(unsigned-byte 64)))


(defun floyd-warshall (path)
  (declare (type (simple-array (unsigned-byte 64) 2) path)
       (values (simple-array (unsigned-byte 64) 2) &optional))
  (destructuring-bind (y x) (array-dimensions path)
    (unless (= y x)
      (break "I expect a square matrix, not ~ax~a." x y))
    (macrolet ((p (j i)
         `(aref path ,j ,i)))
      (dotimes (k x)
    (dotimes (i x)
      (dotimes (j x)
        (setf (p j i)
          (min (p j i) (+ (p k i)
                  (p j k)))))))))
  path)
```

Note 1:
If you have a 3D volume image you should have your indices like this
(aref vol k j i) where k indexes z, j y and i the x-direction. That way
in SBCL and presumably all other implementations the slices are consecutive in memory.

Note 2:
macrolet can save quite a lot of typing. Also look at the implementation of with-arrays in this beautiful library: git://github.com/nikodemus/raylisp.git/objects/box.lisp